# Add angular module on condition

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, conditional-statements, angular-module

I have an array of material modules. I want to add NoopAnimationsModule on mobile devices. I want to to this because material inputs 'blinks' on ios when i close dialog. Code below works as i expect but i have an build:prod error. Any ideas how to solve this?

**error:**

> ERROR in
> app/shared/modules/material-design/material-design.module.ts(73,3):
> Error during template compile of 'MaterialDesignModule'
>
> Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'isMobile' was called.

**code:**

```
 const materialModules = [
      MatProgressBarModule,
      MatCardModule,
      isMobile() && NoopAnimationsModule
   ];

   @NgModule({
      imports: MaterialModules,
      exports: MaterialModules
   })
```

Comment: Try to push the NoopAnimationsModule conditionally

Comment: The other thread didnt really answer my question. MoxxiManagarm conditionally push worked!